# How to acumulate properties of Objects assosiated with the same Key in a Map<K, List<V>> and transform it into Map<K, V>

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I have a class `Records` as follows:

```
public class Records { 
    private BigDecimal price;
    private BigDecimal tos;
    private BigDecimal share;
}
```

And have a Map of type `Map<String, List<Records>>` where each *Key* can be associated with a group of Records.

I want to perform cumulative multiplication on those `Records` instances associated with the same *Key* and produce the resulting Map where every Key is mapped to a single `Records` instance.

For example, in my map the data, if I store data, is like this:

`Map<String, List<Records>>` has data

```
{
"Id1": [ { "price": 3, "share": 4, "tos": 5}, { "price": 2, "share": 3, "tos": 6} ],
"Id2": [ { "price": 1, "share": 7, "tos": 4} ]
}
```

I want to perform cumulative multiplication on data of *Id1* and achieve output like:

`Map<String, Records>`

```
{
"Id1": { "price": 6, "share": 12, "tos": 30},
"Id2": { "price": 1, "share": 7, "tos": 4}
}
```

*My attempt:*

```
private static Map<String, Records> getCumulativeSafFafPaf(Map<String, List<Records>> recordsMap) {

    Map<String, Records> recordData = null;
    Records output = null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Records>> data : recordsMap.entrySet()) {

        List<Records> dbData = data.getValue();

        for (String pid : recordsMap.keySet()) {

            output = new Records();

            if(recordsMap.get(pid).size() > 1) {

                BigDecimal price = BigDecimal.ONE, share = BigDecimal.ONE, tos= BigDecimal.ONE;

                for (Records abc : dbData) {
                    price = DecimalUtil.resetValueWithDefaultScale(price .multiply(abc.getPrice()));
                    share = DecimalUtil.resetValueWithDefaultScale(share .multiply(abc.getShare()));
                    tos= DecimalUtil.resetValueWithDefaultScale(tos.multiply(abc.getTos()));
                }
                output.setPrice(price);
                output.setShare(share);
                output.setTos(tos);
            }
            recordData.put(pid, output);
        }
    }
    return recordData;
}
```

*What I'm stuck on:*

I'm not fully understand how I to store the multiplied data and along with that store the rest of the data.

Comment: @Abra I added the code I tried, what I am not understanding is how I will store the multiplied data and along with that store the rest of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be handy to define a method containing accumulation logic inside the `Records` class instead of manually manipulating the data outside the `Records` instance and then reassigning it via setter, which is less maintainable and violates the [*Information expert principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)).

```
public static class Records {
    private BigDecimal price = BigDecimal.ONE;
    private BigDecimal tos = BigDecimal.ONE;
    private BigDecimal share = BigDecimal.ONE;
    
    public void merge(Records other) {
        price = DecimalUtil.resetValueWithDefaultScale(price.multiply(other.getPrice()));
        share = DecimalUtil.resetValueWithDefaultScale(share.multiply(other.getShare()));
        tos = DecimalUtil.resetValueWithDefaultScale(fl.multiply(other.getTos()));
    }
    
    // getters, constructors, etc.
}
```

Now the code in the method that operates with a map of records can be made leaner.

**Note**

- That in order to perform the transformation, you've illustrated with the sample data you don't need a nested `for`-loop (the inner loop iterating over the keys in your code is redundant).
- Since your objects are *mutable*, it might not be a good idea to share object between different collections (for that reason in the implementations provided below all `Records` instances are not reused, even if there's only one record mapped to a particular key).
- Plural nouns like `Records` are rarely used as names-class. And in such cases it's either a utility class (like `Collections`) which is meant to facilitate various actions which can be performed with instances of a particular type or class which is meant to store multiple instances of particular type. But `Records` is neither of these, therefore I would rather call this class `Record`.

That's your code can be reimplemented using classic Java features:

```
private static Map<String, Records> getCumulativeSafFafPaf(Map<String, List<Records>> recordsMap) {

    Map<String, Records> recordData = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Records>> entry : recordsMap.entrySet()) {
        Records value = new Records();
        recordData.put(entry.getKey(), value);
        for (Records next : entry.getValue()) {
            value.merge(next);
        }
    }
    return recordData;
}
```

That's how it can be implemented with Stream IPA in a more concise way using collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) and *three-args* [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) to perform mutable reduction:

```
private static Map<String, Records> getCumulativeSafFafPaf(Map<String, List<Records>> recordsMap) {
    
    return recordsMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                .collect( Records::new, Records::merge, Records::merge )
        ));
}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/xpU)

Comment: why have you written this twice Records::merge, Records::merge ?

Comment: @Newbie The first *method reference* represents an *accumulator*, the second *combiner*. See [`Stream.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

Answer (score 0):

You basically have the right idea. You just seem to be making it more complicated than it needs to be.

The below code was developed using JDK 19.
(More notes after the code.)

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Records {
    private BigDecimal price;
    private BigDecimal $float;
    private BigDecimal share;

    public Records(BigDecimal thePrice, BigDecimal theFloat, BigDecimal theShare) {
        price = thePrice;
        $float = theFloat;
        share = theShare;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public BigDecimal getFloat() {
        return $float;
    }

    public BigDecimal getShare() {
        return share;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("price: %.2f , float: %.2f , share: %.2f", price, $float, share);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Records> id1List = List.of(new Records(new BigDecimal(3),
                                                    new BigDecimal(4),
                                                    new BigDecimal(5)),
                                        new Records(new BigDecimal(2),
                                                    new BigDecimal(3),
                                                    new BigDecimal(6)));
        List<Records> id2List = List.of(new Records(new BigDecimal(1),
                                                    new BigDecimal(7),
                                                    new BigDecimal(4)));
        Map<String, List<Records>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Id1", id1List);
        map.put("Id2", id2List);
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Records>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            List<Records> list = entry.getValue();
            int size = list.size();
            if (size > 1) {
                Records record = list.get(0);
                BigDecimal thePrice = record.getPrice();
                BigDecimal theFloat = record.getFloat();
                BigDecimal theShare = record.getShare();
                for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
                    record = list.get(i);
                    thePrice = thePrice.multiply(record.getPrice());
                    theFloat = theFloat.multiply(record.getFloat());
                    theShare = theShare.multiply(record.getShare());
                }
                map.put(entry.getKey(), List.of(new Records(thePrice, theFloat, theShare)));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

- You can't use `float` as an identifier in Java since it is a primitive type. Therefore I changed it to `$float`.
- You don't need to iterate the set of keys (from the `Map`), you can iterate the entries. Each entry contains both the key and the value.
- I am not familiar with class `DecimalUtil` but class `BigDecimal` can do the multiplication.

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
{Id2=[price: 1.00 , float: 7.00 , share: 4.00], Id1=[price: 6.00 , float: 12.00 , share: 30.00]}
```